# How to create JSON data using JAVA code in android without using url?

Tags: java, android, json

Can anybody tell me how to create JSON data in java code itself and toast it in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `JSONObject` from any string you like:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Where `jsonString` is, well, a json string like `{name : 'Mark', id: '2'}` or something more complicated.

You can also create an empty `JSONObject` and add the key-value pairs one by one:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
js.put("name", value); //where value can be anything
```

You should read more about [JSONObject.](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Yes , that works thank you.

Comment: No problem. I know it does. This should be a closed question tho because you could've googled this yourself, but I decided to give you a short answer anyway. Consider accepting the answer in order to close the question please.

Answer (score 2):

In your `build.gradle` file inside the `module-leve` (app), add the following:

```
dependencies { 
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3 
}
```

Once you are done adding and syncing the project, simple create a simple java class that represent your json like this:

```
public class Book{

   private String title;
   private int pages;
   private String author;

   public Book(String title, int pages, String author){
      this.title = title;
      this.pages = pages;
      this.author = author;
   }

   //you can add your getters and setters here;
}
```

Now to generate your json String for this class object, simply do this:

```
Book book = new Book("Killing a Mockingbird", 400, "Greg Manning");

//now generate Json string here
String json = new Gson().toJson(book);
```

Now you have your json String to toast or do whatever you want with it!

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Gson is always the viable solution, and a good one too, but I tried to make it as simple as possible :)